# Selenium IDE - Auto removing first backspace from target

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I want to create a Test Case with Selenium IDE.
My test works fine but at the end I want to use the command "assertConfirmation"
The target is " My confirmation message" (The first character is a space)

When I saved the Test Case, Selenium removes the first space at the target field.
It is possible to insert the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn! I don´t know that it is possible to use wildcards with the assertConfirmation command! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to manually add the space in the target of the table. It won't record the white space when you record the test, but it should not trim it if you add it in the target tablecell after you have finished recording.